# ant: include resources in subdirectory to war file

Tags: java, ant, war, build.xml

I would like to include a set of resource files to my war file.

I know that I can specify either `fileset` or `webinf` as an inner element of my `war` element in `build.xml`, but in both of these cases, when I deploy the war file, the resource files end up in either top level directory or `WEB-INF` directory respectively.

I would like to place them into a subdirectory (say, `WEB-INF/resources`). Actually, these resource files are in a subdirectory in my source three already, I just need to include this subdirectory as is to the war file.

How is this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [zipfileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) with `prefix` attribute to add a subdirectory to zip/war file. If the resource files is in `src/resource`, and you want to pack them into `WEB-INF/resource`. Here is the example:

```
<target name="build">
    <war destfile="test.war">
        <fileset dir="webapps">
            <include name="**" />
        </fileset>
        <zipfileset dir="src/resource" prefix="WEB-INF/resource" />
    </war>
</target>
```